# Where does the print output go when running bundled application in OS X

Tags: macos, swift, xcode6

When I code print("Hello world") and "run" from Xcode I see the output in the output window.  When I export/archive and run the application from OSX, where does the print/println output go?

Comment: So using println in a Cocoa program is pointless save for debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the type of project you create. If you create a command-line tool project and run it, the program will run in the Terminal application, and you can see the output in the Terminal window.

If you create a Cocoa application project, you won't be able to see the output from print statements. Print statements are designed for command-line programs, not GUI programs. You would need to learn Cocoa and the ways it displays output to be able to see any output in a Cocoa GUI program.